# SharePoint 2010 Blog Site Custom I Like it locations

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, blog, social

On A SharePoint 2010 blog site does anyone know if you can add the "I Like It" button to the blog post summary's. I would like to add the "I like it" through out the blog so users can tag "I like it" on the posts without having to navigate to the posts directly. (similar to how on Facebook you can click "like" just about anywhere.)

Users don't always understand that when they click "I like it" they have to be on the page for the post to like or tag that specific post.

I have also built some custom  data view pages with SharePoint Designer 2010 that looks like the default blog post views. The tricky part is adding the code so when you click "I like it" it would associate the button with the post it belongs to dynamically.

Thanks ahead

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a JavaScipt + jQuery function I wrote that will 'like' any link that you send it. http://codenutt.net/2012/10/manually-like-links-in-sharepoint-2010.html.

There are two web service calls you make. One is to /vit_bin/socialdatainternalservice.json/GetNormalizedPageUrl. The second is to /vti_bin/socialdatainternalservice.json/AddQuickTag. Chain the two calls together and you can 'like' any link you throw at it.